# Get list of contacts belonging to a specific group

Tags: android, list, contacts, android-contacts

Does anybody know how to get a list of contacts belonging to a 1 specific group in Android?

I need something like this:

```
Select * from contacts where group_id = "1234"
```

I am able to get a list of all contacts OR all groups by using something like this:

```
Cursor groupCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
final ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

while(groupCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String name = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Constacts.DisplayName    ));
    contacts.add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

this is what i use and it works fine for me

```
Uri groupURI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;


    String[] projection = new String[]{
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID ,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID};

    Cursor c = managedQuery(groupURI,
    projection,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID+"="+groupID,
    null,null);
```

this requires you to have the Group id already and that can be found by querying ContactsContract.Groups

Comment: I guess the `CONTACT_ID` is used somehow to look up the contact ?

Comment: I think this has one bug. If groupID of your group is "15" for example. Then if you create a contact with name="15", it will be listed in the cursor! This is because your query only checks GROUP_ROW_ID=groupID, that means: data1=15 in the data table. You should also check that the row in data table is about group membership: **ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"="+"'"+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE**

Comment: @JoonasS I'm a little confused are you saying add "ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"="+"'"+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMe‌​mbership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE" to the query or replace the existing query with it?

Comment: I meant this as additional check. So select is like:  ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"="+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMe‌​mbership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + " AND " +   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID+"="+groupID. This way it will select lines that tell about group membership. Without check, it could find another line that is not about group membership (there are many line mimetypes in data table)

Answer (score 6):

```
public void getSampleContactList(int groupID) {

        contactList = new ArrayList<ConatctData>();
        Uri groupURI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID };

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                groupURI,
                projection,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
                        + "=" + groupID, null, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String id = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));
            Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { id }, null);

            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                ConatctData data = new ConatctData();
                data.name = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                data.phone = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                contactList.add(data);
            }

            pCur.close();

        }
    }

    class ConatctData {
        String phone, name;
    }
```

Hope this will help you to find contact According to group id.

Comment: What to do when you want to use a CursorLoader?

Comment: So all the Data rows have a ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME column?!?

Answer (score 1):

```
    void getlistofcontacts( long groupId ) {
    String[] cProjection = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID };

    Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            cProjection,
            CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "= ?" + " AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(groupId) }, null);
    if (groupCursor != null && groupCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this,"if",1000).show();
        do
        {

            int nameCoumnIndex = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            String name = groupCursor.getString(nameCoumnIndex);

            long contactId = groupCursor.getLong(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));

            Cursor numberCursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Phone.NUMBER }, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);

            if (numberCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int numberColumnIndex = numberCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                do
                {
                    String phoneNumber = numberCursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);

                    Toast.makeText(this,name+phoneNumber,1000).show();
                } while (numberCursor.moveToNext());
                numberCursor.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"no contact are there",1000).show();
            }
        } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());
        groupCursor.close();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"no such group exists",1000).show();
    }
}
```

and call this function from where you want